# Make element remain hidden during animation-delay in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transformation

I have an element that slides across the screen from what I would like to look like off the page and then slide and "land" on the opposite side. I've got the animation down but it seems that during the delay the image just sits on the page in waiting. The delay is because I have another animation that needs to finish before this one starts.

here is my CSS code and I am referencing it via class with a react front end

```
.tester{
  position: relative;
  animation-name: test_css_moving_sideways;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
  left: 90%;
  animation-delay: 2s;  
}


@keyframes test_css_moving_sideways {
  0% { left: 0px; top: 0px;}
  100% { left: 90%; top: 0px; }
}
```

Comment: *"slides across the screen from what I would like to look like off the page"* - So why don't you start it *actually* off the page? As in, set the `left` coordinate to a negative amount. Then it would be hidden until the animation brings it past the left edge of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To fix this you can set `left` property in the css so that it sits at 0% so then when your animation starts it doesnt have to move to a left of 0% (where your animation starts) because it will already be there :)

2) Add `animation-fill-mode` - this controls what happens at the end of the animation. Setting this value to `forwards` will apply the css from the end of the animation to the object

So amend your css to:

```
.tester{
  position: relative;
  animation-name: test_css_moving_sideways;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
  left: 0%;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: none, forwards;
}
```

Comment: Yes but when the animation is finished it goes right back to the left side of the screen because that's what the css is telling it at `left: 0%;` so how do I make it start at the left hidden, or off screen, animate over to the right and then STAY at the right

Comment: @KellysOnTop23 ah sorry I misunderstood :) What you need to do is set the animation-fill-mode: forwards; that will keep the object where the animation ends :) amended my original answer with the new line of code - try that now

Comment: @KellysOnTop23 No worries :) Kindly mark this as the anser :)

Answer (score 0):

Check codepen: https://codepen.io/sasssssha/pen/Nayzpg

You should create one more class (.testerAnimated) and add this classname to element with a js function(if you want animation in a certain time) or you can add it at once(in this case animation starts when page will be loaded). Check it:

```
  .testerAnimated{
  animation-name: test_css_moving_sideways;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;         //play with it
  animation-delay: 2s;  
  }    

  .tester{
  position: relative;
  animation-name: test_css_moving_sideways;
  left: 90%;
  visibility:hidden;  
}


@keyframes test_css_moving_sideways {
  0% { left: 0px; top: 0px;visibility:visible;}
  100% { left: 90%; top: 0px;visibility:visible;}
}
```

Comment: I have react in this project, I know with jQery this is easy but what about react?

Comment: Plus this snippet doesn't STAY on the right side after the animation sends it over there

Comment: I was just saying that I was using react and i knew it was easy with jQuery, didn't say that I saw it in your snippet

Comment: @KellysOnTop23 check my codepen now https://codepen.io/sasssssha/pen/Nayzpg

Comment: contact me via telegram @alexalexalex1 and show me your react code

Comment: @user8685433 this is bad practice. Its quite easily achievable with a simple animation property as shown in my solution. No JS needed :)